# I am able to login in phpmyadmin.but when i am tring to open any database then only loading message is showing

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am able to login in phpmyadmin.but when i am tring to open any database then only loading message is showing.Also i am unable to delete database eventhough user has full privilage full privilage.

i am sharing my [image]config.inc file

Comment: what user are you trying to login with?

Comment: This is showing with all the user.even from root user.